Why is the for loop counting the same index twice?
i have a weird issue with React and the timout function.
For some reason i want a string to be added to a useEffect letter by letter. So i have written this code:
const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState < string > ('')

useEffect(() => {
    const str = "How may I help you today?";
    const letters = Array.from(str);

    const addLetterWithDelay = (index: number) => {
        if (index < letters.length) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setPlaceholder(prevPlaceholder => prevPlaceholder + letters[index]);
                addLetterWithDelay(index + 1);
            }, 1000); // Delay of 1 second
        }
    };

    addLetterWithDelay(0); // Start adding letters from index 0
}, []);

The problem is that the letter is setting it twice
So the output will be: HHooww  mmaayy  II  hheellpp  yyoouu  ttooddaayy??
even if i check with a statement if the last char of the placeholder is the same as letters[index] or not, it still prints that it is not the same and go executing

Related Creating a typewriter effect in React (using JS)

basically, your state updater function prevPlaceholder => prevPlaceholder + letters[index] isn't a pure function. It should be pure so that it always returns the same value given the same input.
